# Can I click tab in TabLayout by coding or method?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have problem when Toolbar collapse. The CoordinatorLayout is not collapse. This problem is cause by I call keyboard. but when I click Tab in TabLayout the CoordinatorLayout is working correct again.

That is why I want to click tab in TabLayout by coding or method.

**UPDATE:** This question is relate with this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31151552/collapse-toolbar-not-work-correctly-when-call-keyboard-from-webview)

Comment: its a bug in the design library, you need to wait until its been fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to elaborate on how you're using a tab layout, but if you have your TabLayout setup with a ViewPager like this:

```
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
```

then you can call .setCurrentItem(int) on the ViewPager like this:

```
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
```

to programatically set the page number. When you have your TabLayout setup with a Viewpager as shown, this will also change your tab in the TabLayout. Here I've set it to 1. Hope this helps!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31151552/collapse-toolbar-not-work-correctly-when-call-keyboard-from-webview
This link is clearly.

Comment: Oh, well then I suppose I haven't answered your edited question then.

Comment: This was the only solution working for me, even if it was no overlapping. Thanks.

Comment: Not the direct approach for this. See my answer. It's working on the new TabLayout inside the new Android Design library. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I have to find the method for myself just to achieve this:

```
 TabLayout.Tab newTab =  tabLayout.getTabAt(int indexnumber); 
 newTab.select();
```

Hope that helps you.

PS. This is using the TabLayout class on the Android design library