# Collapse Toolbar not work correctly when call keyboard from WebView

Tags: android, android-layout, webview, keyboard

After I call keyboard from WebView. There is CoordinatorLayout space (I try to android:background before).

The collapse Toolbar not work correctly when call keyboard from WebView.
but when I removed WebView from Layout. It work correctly.

```
   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.Collapsing
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">


            <com.flaviofaria.kenburnsview.KenBurnsView
                android:id="@+id/imageCover"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/header"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageLogo"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/pic_home"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:paddingBottom="12dp"

                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
        </android.support.design.widget.Collapsing>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Problem is only in Android Support Library old version.
I think this problem is solved now in new version.

Answer (score 1):

try setting `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING)` in your Activity